# Bison Flex reduce/reduce conflict on dangling else with mid action

Tags: c, bison, dangling-else

I am currently moving a fun-project of mine over to bison/flex as parser and have trouble solving a reduce/reduce conflict:

```
// https://github.com/X39/yaoosl/blob/master/code-gen/yaoosl.y#L761-L766
ifthen: YST_IF YST_ROUNDO expression code_ifstart YST_ROUNDC codebody code_ifendnoelse
        | YST_IF YST_ROUNDO expression code_ifstart YST_ROUNDC ifthen_clsd YST_ELSE code_ifelse ifthen code_ifendelse
        ;
ifthen_clsd: codebody
           | YST_IF YST_ROUNDO expression code_ifstart YST_ROUNDC ifthen_clsd code_ifelse YST_ELSE ifthen_clsd code_ifendelse
           ;
```

*Note: stuff prefixed with code_ are the mid-actions*

Could somebody explain to me how to solve this properly and why the "go-to" solution is either wrong or did not worked?
Thanks, X39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the two rules are identical up to the `code_ifelse` (and assuming code_ifelse is an empty rule, like an in-rule action), it can't tell whether to reduce `code_ifelse` before or after the YST_ELSE.  You might be able to fix it by making the two rules consistent with the order of `code_ifelse` and `YST_ELSE`.

Some rules-of-thumb for grammars:

- Don't use symblic names for single char tokens like `'('` and `')'` -- it just obfuscates things and makes the grammar hard to read and understand.
- Don't use in-rule actions unless absolutely necessary -- it's better to create a single token rule with an end-rule action that does what you need.

Comment: Problem i have is that inside the `code_` sections essential setup code for the if-else is emited into some byte array (jump & skip instructions) and removing them is not possible without crafting even more code surrounding them.

Comment: If you can put that code on a rule `else: YST_ELSE { code }` as an end-rule action, its less likely to lead to conflicts.  As such, it will still run before any code related to statements after then else token.